# Sending in-order traversal elements to array

Tags: java, arrays, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
private void inOrder(BSTNode root) {
        if (root.getElem().equals(null)) {
            return;
        }
        inOrder(root.getLChild());
        // print to array, increment 2
        inOrder(root.getRChild());
}
```

So I believe printing to the array occurs at the comment line, since that is usually where the current node is outputted, but not sure how to send the in-ordered elements into an array? If it needs an extra parameter or different return type to make it work, that's ok, I can adjust it since it's a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

1. You've got to pass along the `array` and `index` to your method (signature change).
2. There on you can simply add this line instead of the comment:

   ```
   array[index++]= root.getData();
   ```